# Flutter commands do not work in terminal on Mac OS after update

Tags: macos, flutter, terminal, command

I am running on a Mac, I downloaded Flutter through Git and can confirm that the files are all there, I also successfully updated my path in my ~/.zshrc file. This was all working fine until I ran `flutter upgrade`, after which the `flutter` command stopped working. I confirmed this by running `which flutter` and the output was:

```
/Users/aamir/development/flutter/bin/flutter
```

which looks correct. However, running `flutter` in my terminal gives me back this error:

```
: command not foundpment/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh: line 5:
```

Not sure what's the issue here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I worked this out by manually downloading the flutter SDK then replace it into the original flutter folder. I think it's a problem with the flutter upgrade not being able to completely revert the changes it made after failing to upgrade from the command line.

Comment: Yup this solves it, need to re-install the SDK manually rather than using git to re-install

Comment: yes it is working, but there should be a proper way to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

**For zsh:**

For zsh (Apple M1):

```
   1.Open Terminal
   2.Run: nano ~/.zshrc
   3.Add: export PATH=[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin:$PATH
   4.Run: source ~/.zshrc
   5.restart terminal
   6.Run: flutter doctor -v
```